# Why is the output from my array printing array?

Tags: php, arrays

I am using the results from a db query to populate an array. If I do a var_dump on the array, it looks fine. However, if I try to access the elements of the array by echoing `$myArray[0]` or any other element in the array, all I get is `array`.

Here is an excerpt of my code.

```
$losers = array();
if ($result=mysqli_store_result($con))
  {
  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    {
    //printf("%s\n",$row['Winner']);
    if($row[0]!= "MLB"){
    $data[] = $row;

    echo $row[0] . '<br />';
```

Where I am using the echo for the row element, no problems, it does fine. Here are the results of my var_dump

```
array(4) { [0] => array(4) { [0] => string(3) "MLB" [1] => string(15) "Cincinnati Reds" [2] => string(4) "-137" [3] => string(88) "images/mlb/cred.jpg" } [1] => array(4) { [0] => string(3) "MLB" [1] => string(15) "Minnesota Twins" [2] => string(4) "-128" [3] => string(88) "images/mlb/mtwi.jpg" } [2] => array(4) { [0] => string(3) "MLB" [1] => string(14) "Atlanta Braves" [2] => string(4) "-101" [3] => string(88) "images/mlb/Abra.jpg" } [3] => array(4) { [0] => string(3) "MLB" [1] => string(20) "Washington Nationals" [2] => string(4) "-140" [3] => string(88) "images/mlb/wnat.jpg" } }
```

And this is what happens when I use echo to show the results of the array.

```
ArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArray
```

Comment: what variable are you actually var_dumping?

Comment: it looks like you need to be accessing $row[0][0] to check for "MLB", however thats seems hacky and I think you're taking the wrong approach, you probably should use mysql_fetch_assoc instead of fetch_row.  also, you really should be using mysqli instead of mysql functions.

Comment: var_dump($losers) is what I am using. And I am using mysqli rather than mysql. I hadn't though of using fetch_assoc, mainly because I using mysqli_multi_query as there are 2 queries and I have never used fetch_assoc with multi_query, but yea, that should do it.

Comment: ah, my mistake, I didn't notice the `i`.  too much multitasking.  ya if you use fetch_assoc you can access directly through the column name rather than an array index, faster, better approach as it doesn't require iterating or fall victim to array indices changing if your table gets altered

Comment: NP. Thanks for the fetch_assoc suggestion, that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

That is obviously because element `0` is actually an array. When you try to echo an array, not surprisingly, you get `Array` and a warning. To print an array use `print_r($array, true);`

```
$losers = array();
if ($result=mysqli_store_result($con))
  {
  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    {
    //printf("%s\n",$row['Winner']);
    if($row[0]!= "MLB"){
    $data[] = $row;

    echo print_r($row[0], true) . '<br />';
```

Comment: What you suggested does work. But I have definitely used echo many times with array elements. And you are mistaken to say that you "not surprisingly get array". Echo should and normally does work with arrays.

Comment: @trouble706 "Echo should and normally does work with arrays." - Not true. And the question is this: why is the `$row[0]` variable an array?

Comment: In that case @David Horvath, I hope that you will tell php.net that as they use it on their website. This is straight off the documentation page. [code]$foo = array('bar' => 'baz');
echo "Hello {$foo['bar']}!"; // Hello baz![/code] Not to mention the numerous tutorial websites that show using echo and that I have personally used it numerous times.

Comment: @trouble706 I see it's not very clear to you how arrays work. You should probably focus on mastering that first. In that example they are echoing an array's element, not the array itself, as you are trying to do in the question.

Comment: @php_nub_qq  I guess I wasn't clear in my original question and in looking at the code I am showing above, I do see the confusion because I didn't show where I was echoing the array element. I actually only show where I am echoing the row data which was working, hence the line "Where I am using the echo for the row element, no problems". But to be clear, I wasn't trying to echo the array, just an element out of the array. Such as echo losers[0].

Comment: @trouble706 an element of an array can also be an array